# Delete lines of text file if they reference a nonexistent file

Tags: python, cmd

I have a text file (`images1.txt`) with lists of `.jpg` names and I have a folder (`Bones`) with `.jpg` images. All image names are exactly 42 characters (including the file extension), and each is on a separate line containing the name and some information about the image. For example:

```
OO75768249870G_2018051_4A284DQ0-011628.jpg,1A4502432KJL459265,emergency
OO75768249870G_2018051_4A284DQ0-011629.jpg,1A451743245122,appointment
```

where everything after `.jpg` is my own personal notes about the photos. `Bones` contains many of the 4,000+ images named in `images1` but not all. Using either the command prompt or python, how would I remove the lines from `images1` which correspond to images not present in my `Bones` folder?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python:

```
import os

LEN_OF_FILENAME = 42

with open('images1.txt', 'r') as image_file:
    with open('filtered_images1.txt', 'w') as filtered_image_file:
        for line in image_file:
            image_name = line[:LEN_OF_FILENAME]
            path_to_image = os.path.join('Bones', image_name)
            if os.path.exists(path_to_image):
                filtered_image_file.write(line)
```

Assuming `images1.txt` and `Bones` are in the same folder, if you run the above Python script in that folder you will get `filtered_images1.txt`. It will only contain lines that has a corresponding image in `Bones`.

Comment: Although he did mention the file names are exactly 42 chars but I'd still do `image_name = line.split(',')[0]` just to be safe.

Comment: Thank you, Eason and Siddharth! I don't yet have a high enough reputation to give up-votes but I'll give one once I can.

Comment: On a side note, Siddharth, I'm a "she" not a "he". :)

Comment: @SiddharthShishulkar That's a good point. But I would be more willing to do so if she explicitly said the separator is `,`. :)

Answer (score 0):

This code will read the lines from image1.txt and create an image2.txt with the lines where the file exists in the bones directory.

```
@ECHO OFF
IF EXIST image2.txt (DEL image2.txt)
FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=," %%f IN ('TYPE "image1.txt"') DO (
    IF EXIST "bones\%%~f" (ECHO %%f,%%g >>"image2.txt")
)
EXIT /B
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use the [`findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html):

```cmd
rem /* Search for lines in file `images1.txt` in a case-insensitive manner that literally begin
rem    with a file name found in the directory `Bones` which in turn matches the naming pattern;
rem    then write all matching lines into a temporary file: */
dir /B /A:-D "Bones\??????????????_???????_????????-??????.jpg" | findstr /LIBG:/ "images1.txt" > "images1.tmp"
rem // Overwrite original `images1.txt` file by the temporary file:
move /Y "images1.tmp" "images1.txt" > nul
```